# Insertion sort not working

Tags: java, sorting

The `sortYears()` method should sort the movies by year of release in descending order. It compiles fine, but does not change the order of the movies in the array sorted. What is the least uncomplicated way to fix make it work? Thanks.

`Movie2` class:

```
public class Movie2 implements Comparable<Movie2>
{
 // instance variables 
  private String title;
  private int year;
  private String studio;

  public Movie2(String title, int year, String studio)
 {
  // initialise instance variables
   this.title = title;
   this.year = year;
   this.studio = studio;
  }
public String toString()
{
    String listing;
    listing = title + ", " + year + ", " + studio;

    return listing;
}

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public void setYear(int year)
{
    this.year = year;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
} 
public void setStudio(String studio)
{
    this.studio = studio;
}  
public String getStudio()
{
    return studio;
}
public int compareTo(Movie2 obj)
{ 
  if (title.equals(obj.title))
    return -1;
  else if (title == obj.title) 
    return 0;
  else 
    return 1; 
}
```

}

`TestMovie2` class:

```
 public class TestMovie2
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Movie2[] myMovies = new Movie2[10];
     Movie2[] sorted = new Movie2[10];

myMovies[0] = new Movie2("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia Tristar");
myMovies[1] = new Movie2("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");        
myMovies[2] = new Movie2("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
myMovies[3] = new Movie2("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
myMovies[4] = new Movie2("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");   
myMovies[5] = new Movie2("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
myMovies[6] = new Movie2("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");        
myMovies[7] = new Movie2("Lilo & Stitch", 2002, "Disney");
myMovies[8] = new Movie2("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
myMovies[9] = new Movie2("Monsters Inc.", 2001, "Pixar"); 

System.out.println("   Movies (before change) ");
System.out.println("______________________________");
System.out.println();
printMovies(myMovies);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < myMovies.length; i++)
{
  int next = myMovies[i].getYear();
  int insertIndex = 0;
  int k = i;
  while (k>0 && insertIndex == 0)
  {
   if (next > sorted[k-1].getYear())
   {
     insertIndex = k;
   }
   else 
   {
    sorted[k] = sorted[k-1]; 
   }
   k--;
  }
  sorted[insertIndex].setYear(next);
}

sortYears(myMovies, sorted);
System.out.println(" Sorted by year - descending");
System.out.println("______________________________");
System.out.println();
printMovies(sorted);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();

  public static void printMovies(Movie2[] sorted) 
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++)
        System.out.println(sorted[i]);
 }

 public static void sortYears(Movie2[] myMovies, Movie2[] sorted)
   {

   for ( int i = 0 ; i < myMovies.length ; i++ )
   {
       Movie2 next = myMovies[ i ];
       int insertindex = 0;
       int k = i;
       while ( k > 0 && insertindex == 0 )
       {
          if ( next.getYear() > sorted[k-1].getYear() )
          {
              insertindex = k;
          }
          else
          {
             sorted[ k ] = sorted[ k - 1 ];
          }
           k--;
       }

       sorted[ insertindex ] = next;
   }
```

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about your insertion sort incorrectly. Think about the logic needed to sort from Highest to lowest.
 This is an insertion sort working with an array, but this works, and can be extrapolated to fit your code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] ar1 = {1, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 7, 8, 6, 0};
    int temp = 0;    

     System.out.println ("Unsorted: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
     System.out.print (ar1[i] + "  ");


     for (int i = 1; i < ar1.length; i++) {
         temp = ar1[i];

         // temp < ar1[j]  = Sort in ascending order
         for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp > ar1[j]; j--) {
             ar1[j + 1] = ar1[j];
         }
         ar1[j + 1] = temp;
     }


     System.out.println ("\nSorted: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
     System.out.print (ar1[i] + "  ");
}
```

}